# inspecting ReactJS application styles... missing references to file and line

Tags: reactjs

I am into a component and when inspecting the elements styling with the console, most of them do not get the reference to the style(name of the css file and line). It is very annoying.

Looks like that only the CSS inside the index.html and the 'imported' into the module, there is this info in the console, eg:

import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";

Others, like below, using 'require', there is no reference. I cannot know from which CSS file the styling comes from, etc.

require('./component.countryProfile.css');

[image: just as css]

It looks like I am using Webpack as bundler, this is what I see in my console..

[image: webpack as bundler]

Comment: Which bundler are you using? It looks like your CSS loading happens by way of injecting `<style>` tags into the document, which is why your browser also just shows `<style>`.

Comment: Looks like Webpack (sorry I did not start this app and I am not an expert on React), gonna update the question